# jQuery programmatically find AND count css classes on results?

Tags: jquery

I have a page of database results as list items, each result having between none and several possible css classes dynamically assigned (but not known), for filtering purposes.

Using jQuery how do I programatically find what classes are assigned to each li, AND count the frequency of each class appearance on the page?

I need to be able to access them by the name of the css class, to update html on the page.

Ex html

```
    <ul class="results">
      <li class="a b c d>...</li>
      <li class="a c>...</li>
      <li class="b c f>...</li>
      <!— many more li —>
    </ul>
```

The target output is:
option a 2
option b 2
option c 3
option d 1
option e 0
option f 1
...

Where 'option a' is a filter already on the page, and the count would appear beside it. I have the filter ready to accept the html update:

```
echo ' <span class="' . $row_rsCategories['category'] . '"></span>';
```

Where the category is the name of the filter.

Comment: Use `element.className.split(' ')` to get an array of classes for an element, and loop through them counting each class.

Comment: Okay, and with that HTML what output do you expect?

Comment: @Barmer I'm trying to understand how this works - I can do it for each if hard coded, but the looping to get the count at the same time is escaping me. Can you please post a more comprehensive example?

Comment: Show the output that you want, and then we can explain how to get that (assuming it's possible, and it almost certainly is). If you wanted hypothetical speculation, then I *will* vote to close as off-topic.

Comment: Edited to show desired output

Comment: Sorry if I did something wrong, or offended you @DavidThomas, neither was my intent.

Comment: I'm not offended at all, I just find it difficult to work towards a goal described in language, when the actual output can be so clearly, and unambiguously *shown to us*.

Comment: @DavidThomas Now I know better how to ask questions here, thank you for helping me learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var li = [];
var cnt = [];
$(".results").find("li").each(function () {
    var cls = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");

    var len = cls.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (li.indexOf(cls[i]) < 0) {
            li.push(cls[i]);
            cnt.push(1);
        } else {
            cnt[li.indexOf(cls[i])] = cnt[li.indexOf(cls[i])] + 1;
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/5ySjA/)

Comment: this looks to be right along what I was trying to ask about, thank you. I see how you append the body, and tried modifying that to append the waiting html already on the page, but no success. Any suggestions? http://jsfiddle.net/gchelak/GNZ3z/

Comment: Tried adding $("span.[i]").html(li[i] + cnt[i]); to append the spans above.

Comment: Check console. It throws error.

It should be `$("span."+li[i]).html(li[i] + cnt[i]);`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNZ3z/1/)

Comment: Wow, very cool @Hiral. I really appreciate your help, as well as that of everyone else

Comment: For those trying to put this to use, I found that replacing $(this).attr("class") with var cls = this.className resolved TypeError undefined

Answer (score 1):

This will create an object, `classes`, that contains a count of all classes applied to each list item.

```
var classes = {}; //{a: 2, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1, : 1, f: 1} 
$(".results li").each(function() {
   $.each(this.className.split(" "), function(i, cls) {
       classes[cls] = classes[cls] + 1 || 1;
   });
});
```

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5R5tW/)

Comment: Couldn't make it work. My fault I'm sure. Plugged it into a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gchelak/GNZ3z/

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var classObject = {}
$("ul.results li").each(function() {
    var classes = this.className.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if (classObject.hasOwnProperty(classes[i]))
            classObject[classes[i]]++;
        else
            classObject[classes[i]] = 1;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3FN7U/

Comment: I see how the output is logged to the console. How do I assign it to the appropriate html element waiting for it?

Comment: How do you want to output it?

Comment: Edited my question above to show an example, sorry I didn't include that in the original. Still trying to figure out how best to ask questions here.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach:

```
function classCount(el, prefix){
    // define the prefix, with a default in case a prefix is not supplied:
    prefix = prefix || '';

    /* use the passed-in selector to find the relevant element(s) (with a class)
       to search within:
    */
    var els = $(el).find('[class]'),
        // initialise variables to avoid declaring them within a loop:
        results = {},
        classes = [];

    // iterate over the elements found earlier
    els.each(function(){
        // find the classes of the element:
        classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);

        iterate over those classes:
        for (var i = 0, len = classes.length; i < len; i++){
            /* if there isn't a current property in the results object
               for the current class-name, create and initialise it:
            */
            if (!results[classes[i]]) {
                results[prefix + classes[i]] = 1;
            }
            // if it already exists, increment it:
            else {
                results[prefix + classes[i]]++;
            }
        }
    });

    // return the resulting object to the calling context:
    return results;
}

console.log(classCount('.results', 'option '));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AK86X/).